Runtime issues with spring security configs
Class path resource org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:215) ~[spring-core -6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
Versions used:
Springframework 6.2.4
Spring-security-config 6.2.4
Java 17
spring-boot 3.3
Can anyone provide a resolution to this run time error? WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class is not found in spring-security-config 6.2.4, how can it be resolved?
Tried looking for this class in few other spring-security-config versions, but it was not there

Spring Security version 5.6.5 or older supported to WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter . As you mentioned that You are using spring boot 3.3 which internally support to spring security 6 .
Apart from that Are you using any azure spring version 2 ? if yes , May be that library internally uses the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Supported-Versions

It looks like you are encountering an error where the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class cannot be found. This often happens if you are using a newer version of Spring Security, as WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter has been deprecated in favor of a more component-based approach.
Here is a working configuration using the new recommended approach with SecurityFilterChain:
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig {
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChainApp(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, HttpSecurity http, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) throws Exception {

            MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvcMatcherBuilder = new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
            http.securityMatcher("/**").authorizeHttpRequests( // spiffy the request matcher to be used
                            authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry ->
                            {
                                authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/login")).permitAll(); // permit all for login : example
                                authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers("/**").hasRole("ROLE_NAME");
                            }
                    ).csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())// if you need to ddesable csrf
                    .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                    .authenticationProvider(authenticationProviderApi()).addFilterBefore(authFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .securityMatcher("/**");

            return http.build();
        }
    }

By using this new approach, you should avoid the ClassPathResource.getInputStream error related to the missing WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class. Ensure you are using compatible versions of Spring Boot and Spring Security as per your project's requirements.
For more details, you can refer to this specific Spring configuration file on GitHub : SecurityConfig.java on GitHub
If you need further customization or run into other issues, feel free to ask!

"SecurityConfig is used with SecurityFilterChain, which is a new method replacing WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Below is the SpringSecurityConfig code example I use."
  
    @Configuration
    public class SecurityConfig {
    
            @Bean
            public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        
                httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
                httpSecurity.formLogin().disable();
                httpSecurity.httpBasic().disable();
        
                httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/register" ,
                                                                        "/user/login" ,
                                                                        "/oauth2/google/oauth2_login_address" ,
                                                                        "/oauth2_google_login" ,
                                                                        "/oauth2/naver/oauth2_login_address" ,
                                                                        "/oauth2_naver_login" ,
        
        
                                                                        "/favicon.ico"
        
        
                                                                        ).permitAll()
                        .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and().addFilterAfter(new CustomJwtAuthenticationFilter(jwtParser , jwk , jwtGenerator , gson  , redisTemplate , access_tokenExpireTime) , CorsFilter.class);
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
                return httpSecurity.build();
            }
        
           
        }



you are aware that handing out JWTs to browsers is dangerous and there is a reason spring security does not have such a filter. So delete it, and read the docs how to implement proper security without handing out jwt tokens to browsers.
